# Why does the command 'apt install php' try to install Apache?

Tags: nginx, php, apt, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to install WordPress + LEMP on my Ubuntu 18.04. I have no interest in installing Apache. Why does the PHP installer assume I do?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1160439/533341) on [AskUbuntu: How to install php without Apache webserver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160433/how-to-install-php-without-apache-webserver):

> Ubuntu [package details](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/php7.2) says `php` (`php7.2`) depends on
>   `libapache2-mod-php7.2` OR `php7.2-fpm` OR `php7.2-cgi`.
>
> It seems to default to the first package, which itself depends on
>   `apache2`. But if you install one of the latter first, and `php`
>   afterwards, `apache2` will not be installed.

If you're using nginx, you probably want:

```
sudo apt install php php7.2-fpm
```

Comment: `apt install php7.2-fpm` should be all you need -- it pulls in `php7.2-common` automatically and that's really the meat of it.

Answer (score 16):

As an alternative to the approach used in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1009963/112724) in which you tell APT which dependency you *do* want, you can also specify which you *don't* want. For example in Ubuntu 20.04 (the method is still valid in 18.04 for `php7.2`), to display the dependencies for the `php7.3` package (irrelevant lines omitted):

```
$ apt show php7.3
Depends: libapache2-mod-php7.3 | php7.3-fpm | php7.3-cgi, php7.3-common
```

The | symbol means "or" and is telling you that the dependency can be satisfied by either `libapache2-mod-php7.3`, `php7.3-fpm` or `php7.3-cgi`.

If we go ahead and install the package, we can see that APT will choose the first dependency from the list (`libapache2-mod-php7.3`):

```
# apt install php7.3
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils libapache2-mod-php7.3 libapr1 libaprutil1
  libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap libjansson4 liblua5.2-0 php-common php7.3
  php7.3-cli php7.3-common php7.3-json php7.3-opcache php7.3-readline ssl-cert
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

If you're not happy with that, you can tell APT that you do not want that dependency by placing a hyphen after the name of the unwanted package. If you do so, then APT will instead choose the second dependency from the list (`php7.3-fpm`):

```
# apt install php7.3 libapache2-mod-php7.3-
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php-common php7.3 php7.3-cli php7.3-common php7.3-fpm php7.3-json php7.3-opcache
  php7.3-readline
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

This approach is useful if you know you don't want a particular dependency but are indifferent as to which of the alternatives is used. On the other hand, if you know you need a specific one, use the method in the other answer.